# How to list all the user tables in SQL Anywhere along with their rowcount?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'd like to list all available tables in my DB, and be able to sort and filter by row count.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's easy:

```
select table_name, count
from systable
where primary_root<>0 and creator=1
order by 1
```

or how about adding the column counts and names?

```
select t.table_name, t.count rows, count(*) cols,
  list(c.column_name order by c.column_id) col_list
from systable t
left outer join syscolumn c on c.table_id=t.table_id
where t.primary_root<>0 and t.creator=1
group by t.table_name, t.count
order by 1
```

Hope this helps...

Further information: systable and syscolumn are, since SQL Anywhere 10, only legacy-backwards-compatibility views and Sybase suggests using newer system tables instead... Since I am using version 9 and 11, I stick with these.

Comment: note that primary_root<>0 will then not list any tables without a primary key so you could miss some important ones.